# Include Projector.js from the angular cli

Tags: angular, three.js, angular-cli

I am working on an angular cli based app with the use of three.js in that. I can use the three.js with a `import * as THREE from 'three';`
But I want to add `Projector.js` as well. 
I added the following code in `.angular-cli.json`,

```
"scripts": [ 
        "../node_modules/three/build/three.js",
        "../node_modules/three/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"        
      ],
```

I want to create an object of projector something like,

```
projector: any = new THREE.Projector();
```

I am getting an error in my browser console as,

```
THREE.Projector has been moved to /examples/js/renderers/Projector.js.
```

How can I use the `projector.js` in my component in angular cli app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the way you add `three.js` in your angular project.
You are missing the typings, so once you install the `tree.js` what you have to do is:

`yarn add @types/three -dev` or `npm install @types/three --save-dev`

Also you have to take out your `three.js` and `Projector.js` refs from `scripts` section.

Your error `THREE.Projector has been moved to /examples/js/renderers/Projector.js.` means that `Projector` thing has being moved from the core to examples.

> `/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js` is just the name of an example
>   file. So you have to kind of integrate the content of `Projector.js` in to an angular component.

Things like:  `const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();` will be working fine.

Comment: I try to do it, but still getting the same error message. Do you mean to say the copy/paste the content of `Projector.js` in to my component? Can you explain it more please? how to do it.

Comment: @srijishks I just clarified that part of the answer. Basically you have to convert the code in to angular componemt as if you just copy paste it might not work.

Comment: Should this have `three.js` tag? It looks more like a javascript/typescript/ build system / angular issue that just happens to try to import a module from three (could be any other library)

Comment: `npm install tree`, `npm install @types/three --save-dev` then you can use it in your component by importing that `import * as THREE from 'three'; ` like `const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();`